# Perl: process string with shell command (pipe)

Tags: perl, pipe

Assume a pipeline with three programs:

`start | middle | end`

If `start` and `end` are now part of one perl script, how can I pipe data through a shell command in the perl script, in order to pass through `middle`?

I tried the following (apologies for lack of strict mode, it was supposed to be a simple proof of concept):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n

# Output of "start" stage
$start = "a b c d\n";

# This shell command is "middle"
open (PR, "| sed -E 's/a/-/g' |") or die 'Failed to start sed';

# Pipe data from "start" into "middle"
print PR $start;

# Read data from "middle" into "end"
$end = "";
while (<PR>) {
    $end .= $_;
}

close PR;

# Apply "end" and print output
$end =~ s/b/+/g;

print $end;
```

Expected output:

`- + c d`

Actual output:

none, until I hit ENTER, then I get `- b c d`.  The `middle` command is receiving data from `start` and processing it, but the output is going to STDOUT instead of `end`.  Also, the attempt to read from `middle` seems to be reading from STDIN instead (hence the relevance of hitting ENTER).

I'm aware that this could all easily be done in one line of perl (or sed); my problem is how to do piping in perl, not how to replace chars in a string.

Comment: Another part of the problem is how to close `middle`'s STDIN after writing `start` data to it, while still being able to read from `middle`'s STDOUT until it is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`IPC::Open2`](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC::Open2) for this.

This code creates two file handles: `$to_sed`, which you can `print` to to send input to the program, and `$from_sed` which you can `readline` (or `<$from_sed>`) from to read the program's output.

```
use IPC::Open2;

my $pid = open2(my ($from_sed, $to_sed), "sed -E 's/a/-/g'");
```

Most often it is simplest to involve the shell, but there is an alternative call that allows you to bypass the shell and instead run a program and populate its `argv` directly. It is described in the linked documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I'll remember this for next time!

Comment: And now is that time!

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code does nothing until you hit enter is because you are using perl -n.

-n   causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments
            somewhat like sed -n or awk:

```
          LINE:
            while (<>) {
                ...             # your program goes here
            }
```

The part in your code where you read your file again returns nothing.
If you turn on warnings you will discover that perl doesn't do bi-directional pipes.

Comment: Haha, that's always the way.  I assume you have a much more complicated problem to solve than your example.  Doing bidirectional IO is tough.  [This might help.](http://www.softpanorama.info/Scripting/Perlorama/pipes_in_perl.shtml)

Comment: I fell back to three separate scripts and a shell pipe, it works fine even if it is marginally less tidy!  I was mainly looking at an in-perl piping solution out of curiosity.